# Splitting dictionary objects

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a Blog App and I made a `queryset` which is `showing blog date and likes` of every day since `blog date`, But it is showing in `dictionary` and i am trying to show both instances differently in table like.

| Blog Date | Likes |
| --- | --- |
| 20 Sep. | 6 Likes |
| 21 Sep. | 2 Likes |
| 22 Sep. | 4 Likes |

But it is showing like :-

```
({20: 6},{21: 2},{22: 4})
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blogpost_like = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay
from collections import Counter

def page(request):
    blogpost = get_object_or_404(BlogPost,pk=pk)

    totals = blogpost.likes_set.filter(
        blogpost_like__date=blogpost.date,
        ).annotate(
            date=ExtractDay('blogpost__date'),
        ).values(
            'date'
        ).annotate(
            n=Count('pk')
        ).order_by('date').values()

    results = Counter({d['date']: d['n'] for d in totals})

    context = {'results':results}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

**What have i tried ? :-**

- I have tried

```
lists = [{'id': blog.date, 'name': blog.n} for blog in results ]
```

But it is showing only date like `24` not the likes.

- than i tried

```
json.dumps(list(results ))
```

- than i tried

```
from calendar import monthrange

__, ds = monthrange(blogpost.date)
finalSecond = [data[i] for i in range(1, ds+1)]
```

But it showed

> monthrange() missing 1 required positional argument: 'month'

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TruncDate` to obtain the date:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

totals = blogpost.likes_set.filter(
    blogpost__date=blogpost.date,
).values(
    date=TruncDate('blogpost__date')
).annotate(
    n=Count('pk')
).order_by('date')
```

If you pass this to the context, you can render it with:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Blog Date</th><th>Likes</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for item in totals %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.date|date:"F, d" }}</td><td>{{ item.n }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
{d['date']: d['n'] for d in totals}
```

Makes a dict whose keys are the date and whose vals are the value.  Whilst the data can be extracted from this, it doesn't make any sense, particularly as you store them in a list.  But you already have nicely structured output in your totals, so use that directly without wrapping it all up in a `Counter` of dicts (I have no idea why you are using `Counter`, by the way).

```py
return render(request, 'page.html', {"results": totals})
```

That way your data is getting through to the template nicely. Then your html template just needs to iterate over results:

```html
{% for result in results %}
<tr>
  <td>result.date</td><td>result.n</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did as you said but  it is showing only `date` like `24` in `template loop`

Comment: I made the template more explicit